# Creating Sites in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I just installed SP2013 and I would like to create a number of sites.  However, I would like the URLs to be something like `www.fabrikam.com, www.contoso.com and www.msft.com`.  Is it possible to create 3 independent sites like that?  How would I do it?

A second question is for each site, I would like to set it up as an internet facing site so I assume that the Publish template would be the best.  However, in each site, I would also like to include a blog.  Do I just create a site collection in each with with a different template?

Thanks

Bert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either individual web applications or Host Name Site Collections (HNSC) to achieve what you're after.

Information on creating web applications can be found at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261875.aspx

Information on creating HNSCs and when they should be used can be found at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx

There's also some information on SharePoint design samples at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261995.aspx which you may find useful.

The most appropriate template to use depends entirely on what you're hoping to achieve with the site! Have an experiment to see what works best for your specific application. You should be able to include a blog under each of the site collection templates, and in fact there is a blog site collection template that you can use should you just want to have that as your site.

Comment: Thanks, guys. That is what I was hoping was the answer but I wasn't sure. Both responses answer my questions. Unfortunately, I can only flag one of them as the answer. Bert

Answer (score 0):

To achieve 3 independent domains, the easiest thing to do is to set up 3 web applications and assign a domain to each.

On your second question, any site template can be internet facing. But, if you are looking to have content that revolves around pages, different layouts, and use the other publishing features then go with a Publishing Portal.

And lastly, a blog can be a subsite so you don't need to create a second site collection if you don't have a need in each web application.